# Excel formula or VBA script to group data

Tags: vba, excel

Here is a screenshot of a sample data set that I am trying to work with in Excel 
[image]
I want to use either an Excel formula or a VBA script to populate the firm_anamoly column (it's manually populated right now).

The logic is that for set of rows in a given firm number, if there are more than one "sector23code"s in that set, the output in column "firm_anamoly" should be "firm_count", else "firm_anamoly" should be set to 0.

As you can see for firm_number = 5, since sector23codes are both 3 and 5, firm_anamoly is set to 3, i.e. firm_count.

I have around 500K rows of data that I am trying to work with.

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of linking to a potentially malicious site/file, can you post a screenshot (or preferably, copy/paste data), of what you are trying to accomplish?  I (and I assume others) hesitate to download random files online, especially where macros/code is involved.  Also, please post what you have tried so far, and see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @BruceWayne Appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can go about this.  One way is to do it without converting your range to a table format.

Method 1:
You can enter this formula in cell D2:
{=IF(AND(IFNA(IF(A2=$A:$A,$B:$B,NA())=B2,TRUE)),0,C2)}

This will get you the results that you want I believe but it will probably overwhelm your Excel if you have a less than powerful system.

I would most recommend
Method 2:
Convert your range to an Excel table.  Then enter this formula in the first row of the 'firm_anomoly' column:
{=IF(AND(IFNA(IF([@[firm_number]]=[firm_number],[sector23code],NA())=[@sector23code],TRUE)),0,[@[firm_count]])}

This version will run much more efficiently than Method 1.

Both of these are examples of Array Formulas so when you enter them hit ctrl + shift + enter to get the curly brackets to show up.  Since you have so much data you should definitely back up before entering this formula; array formulas on large data sets can sometimes crash Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I can't get your solution to work. But the formulae return a "Invalid Name Error".

Comment: Which one did you use?

Comment: when you copy the formula in, dont include the curly brackets.  They will be added automatically when you do the ctrl+shift+enter and may cause an error if they are typed in manually.  I was able to get this to work in Excel 2016 so if it does not work on your system, there is not anything else I can do

Comment: Would you please mind taking a look at what I am doing wrong? I have uploaded an Excel file at https://1drv.ms/x/s!Am_nFKPMTx6mgrNnRE_FhPwzFCRNxw. I tried entering the first formula is just one cell. Just so you know, I didn't enter curly brackets when I entered the formula.

Comment: it turns out that I was using Excel 2010. That's why the formula wasn't working. I am in good shape now. Thanks.